# can't connect to the internet after setting up the router N300 netgear wireless

Tags: networking, internet, troubleshooting

I set-up my router which I got from the provider of my internet. So far my internet was working was fine.

I got N300 netgear wireless router. I followed the instructions in the manual in connecting the devices. At first I was still able to connect to the internet until when I logged in the ip address 192.168.1. where I had to do some changes such as the SSID and setting the Paraphrase. 
After that my internet was lost.

Could someone please help me. How to go forward about this?

I also tried to repair one of the connections under "Network connections" but I got, "TCP/IP is not enabled for the connection. Can't proceed"

How to enable the TCP/IP?

One thing more the "internet led" in my router is not lit up. It says that if its not lit up then I have to make sure that the ethernet cable is securely attached to the to the wireless router Internet port and the modem. While checking it, it is so far connected ok.
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Were those changes you were making on the router or on the computer? It sounds like maybe you messed up the connection settings.

Comment: The changes was done when I logged in to the router ip address 192.168.1.1 where I typed the default username and password.

Comment: Can you get back there?

Comment: you mean on the site of the router?

Comment: Sorry, somehow that part about the TCP/IP not registering didn't register in my brain. With no TCP/IP, no addressing will occur and nothing will work.

Comment: what would I do then?I tried to install the driver from the hp site now and now my laptop freezes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP/IP is imperative for your connection to work. You can verify the internet connectivity with a working adapter using the following steps:

If your wired ethernet adapter sill works, the following will verify your internet connection is fine:
Plug directly into the ISP provided device. Configure your computer as directed by your ISP. Attempt to ping. Type IP config at the command prompt and attempt to ping the addresses listed under default gateway and primary DNS. If this works, then there is nothing wrong with your internet connection.

If the router is DHCP (and it probably is by default), then a computer should pull an address when connected - plug into your router with a cable. Assuming your in windows, make sure that you are getting an address assigned (type ipconfig into a command prompt). If you get an address fine, then attempt to ping router address. If that works, then attempt to ping your primary DNS. If you can get that far, your connection with the router is fine and the router's connection to the internet is fine.

For wireless troubleshooting, you should start with the following:
Next step, try to connect with wireless. First look for the SSID that you set in the router. Wait for windows to connect. Again, type ipconfig at the command prompt and repeat the steps above.

To troubleshoot an adapter, first check the device manager. If there is a problem listed there, start by removing the device and restarting the computer, sometimes that will clear an issue. If that doesn't work, updating drivers is a good next step.
If you don't see an issue in the device manager, then something could be wrong with the configuration or a service that governs TCP/IP, and checking into that will depend on which OS you are using.

Comment: Just a moment, I installed an ethernet driver from the HP site because one of the devices say that TCP/IP is not enabled for the connection. Now the laptop seems to freeze :-( Ok I will try to do the first part and will write the result. Btw, I again pull out the cable from router to the modem and now I'm connecting directly to my cable modem, without the router and I can connect to the internet

Comment: Here is the result when I did the ipconfig: Windows IP Configuration: Ethernet Adaptor Bluetooth Network: Media State Media Disconnected - Ethernet adapter wireless Network connection 2: Media State Media Disconnected - Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

Comment: Connection specific DN Suffix :  (blank) - IP Address ...80.219.x.x - Subnet Mask 255.255.240.0  - Default Gateway 80.219.1xx.1. When I did the ping of my ip address it says 0% loss I got reply 4 times